# Get custom field values in alphabetical order

Tags: wordpress, list, field

The function below lists the values ​​of a custom field in the order they are posted. example:

- Frank Capra
- Alfred Hitchcock
- Woody Allen
- Woody Allen
- Frank Capra
- Pedro Almodóvar

I'd like to get this list in alphabetical order and without repetition, with a link to each item `<a href="Woody-Allen">Woody Allen</a>`. example:

- Alfred Hitchcock
- Frank Capra
- Pedro Almodóvar
- Woody Allen

---

This is the code:

```
<?php
$movie_reviews = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&orderby=post_name' );
foreach( $movie_reviews as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
?>
<span>
<?php $director = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "director", $single = true );
if( $director !== '' ) {
echo $director;
} ?>
</span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), you can order posts with `meta_value` like this :

```
$movie_reviews = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts'=>-1,
  'order'=>'ASC',
  'orderby'=>'meta_value',
  'meta_key'=>'director'
));
```

To remove duplicates, you can build an array of directors :

```
$directors = array();
foreach( $movie_reviews as $post ) {
    $director = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'director', true );
}
$directors = array_unique($directors);
```

And after you can display them as you want :

```
foreach ($directors as $director) {
    // display what you want
}
```

**EDIT** : To display only a* directors :

```
foreach ($directors as $director) {
    if (strtolower($director[0])=='a') {
        // display what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect @soju. You can list only directors whose names begin with the letter "a"?

Comment: Great @soju. Thank you very much. You can sort the list by number of occurrences?