# How do I display custom fields in Wordpress in alphabetical order?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, alphabetical

I need to display a custom field on a WP page that contains only values beginning with the letter A, without duplicates. Currently, I am using the code that was given earlier by Soju. This sorts alphabetically, but I can't get it to display only values beginning with one letter:

```
    <?php
    $movie_reviews = get_posts( 
    'numberposts=-1&order=ASC&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=LAST%20NAME' );
    $directors = array();
    foreach( $movie_reviews as $post ) {
        $director = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'LAST NAME', true );
    }
    $directors = array_unique($directors);
    foreach( $movie_reviews as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    foreach ($directors as $director) {
    }
    if (strtolower($director[0])=='') {
        // display what you want
    }
    ?>
    <span><li>
    <?php $director = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "LAST NAME", $single = true );
    if( $director !== '' ) {
    echo $director;
    } ?></br></li>
    </span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You mention "the code that was given earlier by Soju." Is that a reference to another question on this site? Please include a link, so we can understand what you're referring to.

Comment: I second the comment above, as I've misunderstood the question!

Comment: My apologies. Please try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524604/get-custom-field-values-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: Soju provided examples and expert advice, but I just can't figure out how to hook it all together. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off handling this in the database query rather than with PHP. With your current code you will make dozens of database calls which is inefficient.

### Pulling the Records

WordPress stores all the custom fields in the `wp_postmeta` table and can be retrieved as follows.

```
mysql> SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'LAST NAME';
+---------+-------------------+
| post_id | meta_value        |
+---------+-------------------+
|       4 | Spielberg         |
|       6 | AveryTiredman     | <-- in the list twice
|       8 | bLanguage         |
|      10 | aWakeMahn         |
|      12 | dScreensAreBrukin |
|      14 | Aluloby           |
|      16 | AaLetterC         |
|      19 | AveryTiredman     | <-- 
+---------+-------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've created multiple posts with the custom field of `LAST NAME` to replicate your website. As you can see the query above pulls all the last names that I've entered as custom fields.

You can filter and sort the results with the following.

```
mysql> SELECT meta_value AS last_name FROM wp_postmeta
       WHERE meta_key = 'LAST NAME' and meta_value LIKE 'a%'
       GROUP BY meta_value
       ORDER BY meta_value;
+---------------+
| last_name     |
+---------------+
| AaLetterC     |
| Aluloby       |
| AveryTiredman | <-- only shown once
| aWakeMahn     |
+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see the above query only pulls unique records, that start with the letter `"a"`, and it orders them by name.

**Note:** I changed the column name to be more relevant with `SELECT meta_value AS last_name`.

### Using with WordPress

WordPress has its own database class with a method called [`get_results()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) that let's you run your own query. The method will return an array of objects that will let you access the column names.

```
<?php $directors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value AS last_name FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'LAST NAME' and meta_value LIKE 'a%' GROUP BY meta_value ORDER BY meta_value") ?>
<ol>
  <?php foreach( $directors as $director ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $director->last_name ?></li>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

I know that you're new to this and I tried to lay it out so you can understand what's going on. If you have any questions just let me know and I'll try to help you out.

---

### Update

The easiest way to make a page with links to filter through directors is with a custom page template. Basically, create a file named `page-directors.php` with the following content. Then add a new page and set the template to `"Directors Page"`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Directors Page
 */

// get a distinct set of the first letters available
$letters = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT substring(meta_value, 1, 1) as letters FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'LAST NAME' ORDER BY meta_value", ARRAY_N); 

// get the letter from the URL
// and make sure there is only a single letter
$director_letter = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'director', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-z]$/i')));

// set a default if none is available
if( $director_letter == false ) {
  $director_letter = 'a';
}else {
  $director_letter = strtolower($director_letter);
}

// don't trust user's input
$director_letter = mysql_real_escape_string($director_letter);

// same query as before but includes letter from user
$directors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value AS last_name FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'LAST NAME' and meta_value LIKE '$director_letter%' GROUP BY meta_value ORDER BY meta_value");

get_header();
?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <!-- 
        CSS:
        #director_letters li {
          list-style: none;
          display: inline;
        }
      -->
      <ol id="director_letters">
        <?php foreach( $letters AS $letter ) : ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo add_query_arg('director', strtolower($letter[0])) ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($letter[0]) ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </ol>

      <h2>Directors</h2>

      <ol>
        <?php foreach( $directors AS $director ) : ?>
          <li><?php echo $director->last_name ?></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </ol>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

### Update #2

If you take the code and SQL queries I've written for you already you should be able to figure it out. I don't want to just give you the answer because you won't learn that way. So here's what I'll do instead. I'm going to give you the steps that you need to take to accomplish it and let you figure it out. If you have any questions or you get stuck, post a comment and I'll help you out.

1. You'll need to create another custom page template that will take the director's last name as a `GET` parameter. It will be exactly the same as what that I've used to show the first letters of the directors last names.
2. Next, you will need to query the `wp_postmeta` table and select the `post_id` `WHERE` the `meta_value` equals the director's last name.
3. You will need to loop over the post ids and display the post's title.

> **Note:** A function that you will find handy is [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_title). You can pass the id of a post and it will return the title.

Everything I've shown you so far can be used to answer your question. But, as I said before, if you run into a problem that you can't figure out let me know.

Also, once you've completed this feature please add the code back to your original question. There's a good chance that we can greatly improve the efficiency of it :)

P.S. If you have don't understand some of the code that I've supplied you, please let me know. It won't do you any good to have code that you don't understand :)

### Update #3

I made a [video explaining all the steps](http://youtu.be/8eYE-PEaGB0) from the beginning. It starts with pulling out the director's last names, then showing all the letters, and finally showing all WordPress posts with the director.

Comment: Unbelievable. I hope they're paying you well! This is exactly what I was looking for and I really appreciate it. I was so stuck on trying to learn PHP, I didn't realize you could do this with a SQL query. Oh no... now I have to learn a whole other language! : )

Comment: @Goldnuggets haha thanks. Glad you got it working, but don't worry, SQL is a lot of fun. Cheers!

Comment: I actually had one more question, as long as this doesn't take much of your time up. Is there a simple way to hook each of the returned entries to a URL that points to all search results of that last name? Thanks!

Comment: unbelievable! Last thing I want to do is wrap each of those returned results in an anchor tag so when they're clicked, it'll take me to a page that displays all posts where that custom field has been used. OH man... please feel free to ignore this, you've been awesome enough already. Thank you again very very much!!

Comment: @Goldnuggets how's it coming, were you able to get it working?

Comment: Shoot.. I've been trying to get it to work now over the past day, to no avail. For the SQL portion, I've entered the following: $directors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id AS last_name FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 'LAST NAME' and meta_value LIKE '$director_letter%' GROUP BY meta_value ORDER BY meta_value");

Comment: For the call to display links to post_ids, I entered this:            <?php $post_id = array();
$posts = get_posts( $post_id);
foreach( $posts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);  ?><h2 class="title">
<?php // if there is a parent, display the link
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); 
if ( $parent_title != the_title(' ', ' ', false) ) {
echo '<a href=' . get_permalink($post->post_parent)
. ' ' . 'title=' . $parent_title . '>' . $parent_title
. '</a> » ';
    } 

    ?>
    </h2>
   
   <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ol>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

Comment: I super appreciate how awesome you've been, and def want to learn all this. But admittedly, after struggling over this for a little while, I'm finding a lot of this is beyond me. :( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Goldnuggets hey, thanks for getting back with me. I made a video explaining the full process of making this feature that you want. I figured it would be easier to see all the steps I took when writing the answer so you could see where things went. See the update #3

Comment: @Goldnuggets I'm sorry to keep nagging you, but I wanted to know how it's coming. Were you able to get it working or is there a problem?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for not reaching you back yet. Hurricane Sandy kinda kept me out of the loop for a few. I'm just now watching your video tutorial and will get back to you soon. Thank you again for all your help. This has been a fascinating learning process.

Comment: @Goldnuggets oh man, I'm sorry to hear that. I hope everything is okay. If you have any questions just let me know.

Comment: Ok back in action! Your video is incredible. I have everything down except for one last item! Using your example, finding all results for 'Needham' works great! But what if I want results from other directors? Can I write the 'meta_value= 'Needham' " section to refer to any director that I've chosen from the list? Thanks!

Comment: @Goldnuggets thank you, I figured a video tutorial would be helpful. As for your question, yes, when you change the value in the single quotes it will find records that match the search criteria.

Comment: @Goldnuggets did I miss understand your question? Do you want to show movies by two directors on the same page? The syntax for that is `WHERE ... OR ...`. In your application that would be `WHERE meta_value = 'Needham' OR meta_value = 'Spielberg'`.

Comment: I want to show only movies by a single director on one page... but have lots of different directors. So I'm wondering if there's a way to tell my application to show movies by the meta value that was clicked. This way, the results will be dynamic depending on whichever director is chosen from the list. Does that make sense? Thank you again so much!!!

Comment: Nevermind!! Just got it. : ) I changed the variable it's looking for to $Directors and now it's pulling the right posts! Thanks again for everything!!